# Flurry Dependency analysys warning

Tags: ios, build, flurry

I'm trying to add the flurry SDK to my projet but I've this warning: no rule to process file '$(PROJECT_DIR)/Flurry iPad SDK v4.0.6/Flurry iOS API Documentation/assets/jquery.js' of type sourcecode.javascript for architecture armv7

Thank you for your help,

Alexandre

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the .js file from the Compile Sources section of your target's Build Phases and put it into the Copy Bundle Resources phase instead.

Comment: Thank you, this works for 4 of my 6 warnings. The other 2 are : directory not found for option '-L/Users/alex/Documents/IOS/BudgetManagerTabBar/BudgetManagerTabBar/Flurry/Flurry' AND ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/alex/Documents/IOS/BudgetManagerTabBar/BudgetManagerTabBar/Flurry/FlurryAds'

Comment: All I can tell you about those is that you've specified two library paths in your Build Settings for the linker to search which it thinks don't actually exist.  Check for the existence of the two locations it's complaining about.

Comment: @Alexandre those are different issues, you would need to create a new question for those.

Comment: Yes, I've removed those links from the "library search paths" and the warning is gone.